# JTable Rows Not Rendered in Expected Colors

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a jtable , a customtablemodel and a customcellrenderer with the NetBeans IDE.
 I want to have different colors for different rows. But anytime I run the application ,
 the rows are not painted as expected. 
 The code snippets are provided below.

This code is from the jtable :

```
  duesTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

  duesTable.setModel(duestableModel);
  TableColumn tcol = duesTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
  tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer2());
  duesTable.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

this code is from the TableCellRenderer

```
  public class CustomTableCellRenderer2 extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

 @Override
 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, 
 Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

if (isSelected) {
cell.setBackground(Color.green);
} 
else {
if (row % 2 == 0) {
cell.setBackground(Color.green);
}
else {
cell.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
  }
}
return cell;
  }
 }
```

This is from the Table Model.

```
        public class DuesTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModelListener  {

       private List<List<Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
       private String[] header = { "ID"," PAYMENT YEAR" , "AMOUNT"};  // Payment year is a date
      datatype

       private int minRowCount = 5;    

      public DuesTableModel()
     { super(); }

      public List<List<Object>> getDataList() { 
    return dataList;
       }

     public void setDataList(List<List<Object>> dataList) {  
      this.dataList = dataList;
      fireTableDataChanged();       
      fireTableStructureChanged();        
      }


       @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
       return Math.max(minRowCount, dataList.size());
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
         return header.length;
        }

        public void setHeader(String[] header) {
       this.header = header;
        }

       public String[] getHeader() {
        return header;
       }

      @Override
     public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
      {       
       int x = 0;
      for(List<Object> l : dataList)
      {
      if(x == row)
       {  l.set(col, value);}
      x++;        
      }
     fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);    
     }


     @Override
      public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        Object value = null;
       if(rowIndex < dataList.size())      
       {value = dataList.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);}
      return value;
       }

      @Override
      public String getColumnName(int col) {
      return header[col];
     }


    @Override
     public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)
      {        
        switch (column) {
        case 0:
            return Integer.class;
        case 1:
            return Date.class;
        case 2:
            return Double.class;
        default:
            return String.class;
    }          
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {          
    return true; //col != 1;
    }


   @Override
   public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
  }    
  }
```

Any suggestion to get the desired result.

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. And for your SSCCE just use the DefaultTableModel, because the TableModel is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Cross posted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/638515/GUI/java/JTable-Render-Rows-Colors#2929438

Comment: Hate to think how the user is suppose to distinguish between a selected and unselected row, however, have you made sure that the cell render is opaque...?